# (php) search record from database with click search button

Tags: php

This is the code search.php

```
<?php include_once('include/header.php'); ?>
<body>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(~0);

    require_once 'db/db.php';


$strKeyword = NULL;

if (isset($_POST["txtKeyword"])) {
    $strKeyword = $_POST["txtKeyword"];
}
?>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="search.php">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>Keyword
                <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $strKeyword; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</form>

<?php
$perpage = 2;
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$start = ($page - 1) * $perpage;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE cust_ic LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' OR cust_hp_contact1 LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' limit {$start} , {$perpage}";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Race</th>
            <th>IC Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Contact Number (Home)</th>
            <th>Handphone Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Join Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    $no = 1;
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_gender'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_race'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_ic'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_add1'] ?>
                <?php echo $result['cust_add2'] ?>
                <?php echo $result['cust_postcode'] ?>
                <?php echo $result['cust_town'] ?>
                <?php echo $result['cust_state'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_home_con'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact1'] ?>
                <?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact2'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_email'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_join_date'] ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="crud/edit.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">Edit</a> || 
                <a href="crud/delete.php?id=<?php echo $result ['id']; ?>">Delete</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
<?php
$sql2 = "select * from customer_info ";
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$total_record = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
$total_page = ceil($total_record / $perpage);
?>
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
            <a href="search.php?page=1" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) { ?>
        <li><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li>
            <a href="search.php?page=<?php echo $total_page; ?>" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<?php include_once('include/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This page direct show me the result from database. How I can click search button and show me the result, dont want automatic display the result without I click search button.

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I click search button"?

Comment: when I run this file directly display the result, I want to display result when I click search button.. how can I code it?

Answer (score 1):

You should get records on `post` request not on `get` request.

```
if (isset($_POST["txtKeyword"])) {
    $strKeyword = $_POST["txtKeyword"];
    // execute query here
   sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE cust_ic LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' OR cust_hp_contact1 LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' limit {$start} , {$perpage}";

   $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand you mean. can u explain in detail?

Comment: When `$_POST["txtKeyword"]' is set that means you want to search, so you retrieves results from database and display results. Else you don't retrieve results.

Comment: when I run this file directly display the result, I want to display result when I click search button.. how can I code it?